# Cannot parse JSON array saved in PostgreSQL JSON field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a JSON field inside a PostgreSQL database, with the following content:

`[{"id":"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a5","content":"Alfredo"},{"id":"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a2","content":"Re Duarte"}]`

The relevant piece of migration file:

```
create_table :module_form_entries do |t|
    t.json :payload
    t.references :application, foreign_key: true
    t.references :fb_user, foreign_key: true
    t.timestamps
end
```

I'm trying to loop through objects inside the collection. Already tried these methods with the corresponding results:

```
//calling
logger.info(self.payload.as_json)
//returns
[{"id"=>"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a5", "content"=>"Alfredo"}, {"id"=>"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a2", "content"=>"Re Duarte"}]
//calling
logger.info(self.payload.to_json)
//returns
[{"id":"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a5","content":"Alfredo"},{"id":"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a2","content":"Re Duarte"}]
//calling
logger.info(self.payload.to_json[0])
//returns
[
//calling
logger.info(self.payload[0])
//returns
nil
//calling
logger.info(self.payload.first)
//returns
nil
//calling
logger.info(self.payload)
//returns
[{"id"=>"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a5", "content"=>"Alfredo"}, {"id"=>"4e40bc97-a436-45c3-b603-733bf3b4f0a2", "content"=>"Re Duarte"}]
//calling
logger.info(self.payload.class)
//returns
Array
```

The first cases are just to check how the JSON array is modified by each method. Trying to get the [0] or first object returns nil, which is weird because it's a JSON array.

Comment: What does `self.payload` return? If you're using a JSON column, it _should_ be returned as a hash.

Comment: `to_json`/`as_json` will render `String`s in `JSON` notation as is evident by `self.payload.to_json[0] #=> "["`  as for why `self.payload` returns `nil` I cannot explain this. As mentioned by @DanielWestendorf, seems the only thing you missed in these examples was `self.payload` can you show the output of `self.payload.inspect`?

Comment: Thanks! I've just added what `self.payload` returns.

Comment: what about self.payload.class?

Comment: It returns `Array`, just added that to the question. It's either some super weird edge case or I'm just missing something.